In Safari 17, the page automatically scrolls to the top after the user clicks on a checkbox. How can this be fixed?
I have a post filtering form in WordPress. When I click on a checkbox, the page jumps to the top.
The form is not submitted, but a fetch request is made.
The checkbox is not located at the top of the page.
Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?
Website: https://7-stars.agency/ru/vacancies/
Workarounds like window.scrollTo do not help.
